# In Castle Windsor, can I register a Interface component and get a proxy of the implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, interceptor

Lets consider some cases:

```
_windsor.Register(Component.For<IProductServices>().ImplementedBy<ProductServices>().Interceptors(typeof(SomeInterceptorType));
```

In this case, when I ask for a IProductServices  windsor will proxy the interface to intercept  the interface method calls.
If instead I do this :

```
_windsor.Register(Component.For<ProductServices>().Interceptors(typeof(SomeInterceptorType));
```

then I cant ask for windsor to resolve IProductServices, instead I ask for ProductServices and it will return a dynamic subclass that will intercept virtual method calls.
Of course the dynamic subclass still implements 'IProductServices'

My question is : Can I register the Interface component like the first case, and get the subclass proxy like in the second case?.

There are two reasons  for me wanting this:
1 - Because the code that is going to resolve cannot know about the ProductServices class, only about the IProductServices interface.
2 - Because some event invocations that pass the sender as a parameter, will pass the ProductServices object, and in the first case this object is a field on the dynamic proxy, not the real object returned by windsor. Let me give an example of how this can complicate things : Lets say I have a custom collection that does something when their items notify a property change:

```
private void ItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int senderIndex = IndexOf(sender);
        SomeActionOnItemIndex(senderIndex);
    }
```

This code will fail if I added an interface proxy, because the sender will be the field in the interface proxy and the IndexOf(sender) will return -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
_windsor.Register(Component.For<ProductServices, IProductServices>()
   .Interceptors(typeof(SomeInterceptorType));
```